# catching unknown exception

Tags: c++, mfc, exception

In the release version of my code one line is throwing an exception and I don't know what type of exception it is so I can't catch it correctly or figure out the problem.

I using the catch(...) but that's pretty much worthless.

here is some pseudo code

```
 try
  {
    m_mmwIPC = gcnew NiftyIPC(gcnew String("Monitor"), true);
  }
  catch (CException* e)
  {
    TCHAR   szCause[255];
    e->GetErrorMessage(szCause, 255);
    CString errorStr = szCause;
    RemoveLineFeeds(errorStr);
    OutputDebugString(errorStr);
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    OutputDebugString(L"Unknown exception\n");
  }
```

So, is there any way to get any details on the thrown unknown exception?  Just a type would be great.

thanks

Comment: (random thought that just flashed through my mind) It is a shame that the wording for C++0x `auto` is "deducted from its __initializer__", and there really isn't an initializer here even though the type is more or less obvious to the compiler. Otherwise one could write `catch(auto excpt)`. Though of course it would probably be an immense burden for the compiler having to generate all those separate code paths...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really, it could be an `int`, a `const char*` or a `RhubarbPie` über-smart pointer.

However:

- Try catching `std::exception` too. That will catch a lot of  C++ native exceptions.
- Your exception is probably a .NET one, so try to catch that one, not the MFC Base exception. (It looks like you're doing C++/CLI. In that case, .NET-exceptions end up in the catch-all clause)
- Also, exceptions are usually meant to be caught by reference in C++ 
  (*Update: MFC apparently uses throw-and-catch by pointer. That works too, as long as you catch what is thrown.*)
- It might also help to use __try and __catch, since some "hardware" exceptions like stack-overflow, access violation, etc, are also unknown exceptions on Windows. The syntax for catching them are a bit differently, but you get an exception identifier that can be used to report the type of exception thrown. I use that to print stack-traces on fatal errors in our apps.

Comment: Although it's a fair point that in C++ it's nicer to catch by reference, MFC I believe tends to follow a convention of catching by pointer. That doesn't stop user code from catching by reference, tho'.

Comment: I think this is the best approach I can make.  Try to catch all the generic types and log them as best I can.  MFC does catch by pointer, but that shouldn't matter since under the covers a reference is just a pointer anyway.

Comment: @lunknown: Ok. I didn't know about MFC. Note that a reference to X and a pointer to X is two unrelated types to the compiler, so the catch() clause won't auto-convert with each. You need to catch by pointer if exceptions are thrown by pointer, or catch by ref if thrown by value (or ref, I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

As you specify the use of MFC, then I will make the assumption that you're working with a version of Visual Studio.  If this is the case and you are able to run your program in debug mode, then you can set the debugger to break on unhandled exceptions.  This would require removing the `catch(...)` part of your code, but it should break into the debugger at the correct point, and provide you with useful information on the exception itself.

I refer you to the Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: The exception only happens in release mode like all ugly bugs I seem to discover. <grin>

Comment: @luknown: You can run the debugger on release mode code (esp if you build with debug info). Just don't expect the values on the stack to be reported correctly by the debugger when debugging optimized code.

Answer (score 1):

Every exception should derive from `std::exception`, then you can use RTTI. Standard catch block is

```
catch (const std :: exception & e) {
    // e .what ();
    // typeid (e);
}
catch (...) {
    // WTF ?!?!?
}
```

In c++0x you can use `std::current_exception` and perhaps pass the `exception_ptr` into some clever library for analysis.

Bear in mind that exceptions can be buildins and other types which have no RTTI, which is why you should always derive from std::exception.

Comment: "Every exception should derive from std::exception" : is that the case with MFC? I know that CException derives from CObject - does it also derive from std::exception?

Comment: Possibly but not neccessarily. Check `NULL != dynamic_cast<const std::exception *>(CExecption_pointer)`

Comment: Actually, if you have the above catch block, your CException object will bind to it if and only if it derives from std::exception (and if no more-specific matching block sneaks in first)

Answer (score 0):

No here isn't.  catch( ...) should only be used as a last resort really.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to *not* catch the error and run the programmer in the debugger (this is possible in Release mode). Visual Studio will break into the code where the uncaught exception occurs.